# Manejo de fechas con tipo de datos int

Tags: date, formato

Estimados: sigo con mis problemas de fecha y en esta oportunidad estoy tratando de comparar datos de un campo (fecha_alta) de una tabla contra una variable.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('base.dbo.tabla_ejemplo') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE base.dbo.tabla_ejemplo
END

CREATE TABLE base.dbo.tabla_ejemplo (fecha_alta decimal(8,0));
GO


INSERT INTO tabla_ejemplo (fecha_alta)
VALUES
(20190701),
(20150801),
(20191212),
(20190801),
(20190112),
(20180801),
(20181212),
(20200601);
GO

Declare @AAAAMM int;

Declare @fecha_alta int;

SELECT @AAAAMM = 202001;

SELECT CAST(LEFT(cast(fecha_alta as varchar(8)), 6) AS DECIMAL(6, 0)) as Fecha_alta
     , @AAAAMM as [AAAAMM]
     , CASE
       WHEN CAST(LEFT(CAST(fecha_alta as varchar(8)), 6) AS DECIMAL(6, 0)) < @AAAAMM then @AAAAMM - CAST(LEFT(CAST(fecha_alta as varchar(8)), 6) AS DECIMAL(6, 0))         
                else  13 - SUBSTRING(CAST(fecha_alta as varchar(8)), 5, 2)
       END as [Resultad_esperado]
from tabla_ejemplo;
```

Esta consulta me da este resultado:

```
Fecha_alta  AAAAMM  Resultad_esperado
201907      202001  94
201508      202001  493
201912      202001  89
201908      202001  93
201901      202001  100
201808      202001  193
201812      202001  189
202006      202001  7
```

pero mi pretención es que arroje este resultado:

```
Fecha_alta  AAAAMM  Resultad_esperado
201907      202001  6
201508      202001  53
201912      202001  1
201908      202001  5
201901      202001  12
201808      202001  17
201812      202001  13
202006      202001  -5
```

Desde ya se agradece su colaboración.

Comment: ¿Algún motivo particular para guardar la fecha de esa forma tan poco ortodoxa?

Comment: Y si... te da esos numeros porque son int, no fechas, y si restas int, no resta como corresponde si no como numeros comunes. Aprovecha a hacer el [tour] y tambien mira [ask].en realidad tenes que convertir los numeros a fechas, y no al reves...

Comment: Hola Eduardo el campo en la tabla  es decimal (8,0)  y si quiero convertirla previamente surge el error de que no se puede convertir de decimal a fecha por eso mi idea de trabajar con formato plano, pero yo soy un principiante si tenés alguna alternativa, se acepta gratamente.

Answer (score 0):

El `GO` en el código que publicaste me hace suponer que estás trabajando con SQL Server.

Y con base en la tabla de resultados esperados, infiero que tu requerimiento es la cantidad de meses transcurridos entre `Fecha_alta` y la fecha en la variable `@AAAAMM`.

Existe la función [`DATEDIFF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que hace exactamente lo que quieres sin muchas complicaciones pero tienes que trabajar con fechas.

**Actualización:** En vista de que la tabla real tiene las fechas almacenadas como `decimal (8,0)` modifico el código para manejar ese caso.

Las siguientes modificaciones producen el resultado requerido:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('base.dbo.tabla_ejemplo') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE base.dbo.tabla_ejemplo
END


CREATE TABLE base.dbo.tabla_ejemplo (fecha_alta  decimal(8,0));
GO


INSERT INTO tabla_ejemplo (fecha_alta)
VALUES
('20190701'),
('20150801'),
('20191212'),
('20190801'),
('20190112'),
('20180801'),
('20181212'),
('20200601');
GO

--      date en lugar de int
--               |
--               V
Declare @AAAAMM date = '20200101';

SELECT FLOOR(fecha_Alta / 100) as fecha_Alta, 
       FORMAT(@AAAAMM,'yyyyMM') as AAAAMM, 
       DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(fecha_alta AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), @AAAAMM) as Resultad_esperado
FROM tabla_ejemplo;
```

La división `fecha_Alta / 100` produce un resultado con 2 decimales y la función [`FLOOR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)`(fecha_Alta/100)` devuelve la parte entera y de esta forma se obtienen los dígitos equivalentes al año y el mes. Es cierto que se puede convertir a varchar y extraer los primeros 6 pero es más eficiente trabajar con números.

Comment: Gracias Pablo la respuesta tuya llega al resultado esperado, pero cuando traslado esta tabla_ejemplo a la tabla real me surge la diferencia, porque el campo en la tabla real es decimal (8,0) y si quiero convertirla previamente surge el error "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

Comment: Hola @martin, acabo de modificar mi respuesta para que funcione con los datos de la tabla real